# convert MS access query - multiple condition - to SQL Server

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can somebody help me convert this access query to SQL. 
It works perfectly in Access.

Have fiddled around long enough:

```
SELECT cr2.filename, cr2.branch, cr2.typeA, cr2.typeB, cr2.total, 
[typeA]/1.2 AS netA, [typeB]/1.2 AS netB, cr2.receipt, cr2.qty, 
cr2.orderid, cr2.method, cr2.date, ([netA]+[netB])*0.2 AS Vat, 
([Vat]+[netA]+[netB])-[total] AS Diff
FROM cr2
WHERE (((cr2.branch)="SW1") 
AND ((cr2.method)="Visa" OR (cr2.method)="MCard") 
AND ((cr2.date) Between #4/1/2015# And #4/30/2015#)) 
OR (((cr2.branch)="SW1") 
AND ((cr2.receipt)="Y") 
AND ((cr2.method)="Coupon") 
AND ((cr2.date) Between #4/1/2015# And #4/30/2015#)) 
OR (((cr2.branch)="SW1") 
AND ((cr2.qty)<=5) 
AND ((cr2.method)="Coupon") 
AND ((cr2.date) Between #4/1/2015# And #4/30/2015#))
ORDER BY cr2.date;
```

Additionally, is it possible to have a `GROUP ON` the branch?

Comment: Replace double quotes with single quotes; dates into YYYY-MM-DD with single quotes replacing `#`. Re-define calculated columns when used in another column (i.e., `[VAT]`). Why the branch group by if you do not use aggregates: Count(), Sum(), etc.?

Comment: So I can change it to an aggregate function if I wish ? Thought there were too many conditions